# Implementing a manifest.json file for a VueJS app to set conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, android-manifest, manifest

I have added a manifest.json file to my Vue app. This file lives in a folder called scripts which is then referenced on my main.js. However, it really doesn't do anything. For example, I have it set up to set the display as standalone, fix the orientation to portrait and also add a title and bookmark icons when the user adds it to bookmark in their browser. Unfortunately, for some reason it doesn't seem to work at all. Where have I gone wrong?

The manifest.json is as follows

```
{
  "name": "Bake Bread App",
  "short_name": "Breadr",
  "theme_color": "blue",
  "background_color": "blue",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "Scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/bookmark-icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

Then if we go up a level (out of this scripts folder) and to main.js, I have

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

// FILTERS
Vue.filter('snippet', function(value) {
    return value.slice(0,100);
});

Vue.component('loading-screen', {
  template: '<div id="loading">Loading...</div>'
});

import json from './scripts/manifest.json'
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            myJson: json
        }
    }
}

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

In addition, I added `<link rel="manifest" href="js/manifest.json">` in my index.html as instructed via the Google Developers Documentation.

Comment: what should the manifest do?  https://codesandbox.io/s/4z811r3yjx

Comment: I want my app to be in portrait only, have no web address bar, set icons for add to bookmark and eventually include the add to homescreen option. developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working in Vue `img` `src` neds to be defined in the `Data object` with `require()`

and webpack needs to know about the images.

- [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4z811r3yjx)
- you can modify your manifest and use a getter function for your resources.
- Or you can `use require("path to the resource (not the manifest string)")` in your data object.

---

helloWorld.vue:

```
 <template>
    <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>

    <ol v-for="x in myJson.icons" :v-bind="x" :key="x">
      <li>
      <div> name: {{x.name}}</div>
      <div> name: {{x.sizes}}</div>
      <div> name: {{x.type}}</div>
      <img :src="getSrc(x.src)" alt="wrong..">
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import json from "../../manifest.json";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      myJson: json,
      msg: "Manifest:"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getSrc(src) {
      return require("../assets/" + src);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

modified icon json:

```
  "icons": [
    {
      "name": "logo",
      "src": "logo.png",
      "sizes": "99x99",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "name": "logo2",
      "src": "logo.png",
      "sizes": "929x929",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I get loads or errors. It is worth knowing that I am trying to get my manifest added using the import method on my App.Vue. I am using routing. If I was to add it to components I would be repeating code. I am unable to import any js file using import or any other method as well.